# Rails render search bar sunspot search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, render, sunspot

I am using to method for the same view and using render, it all works fine but the search is still based on the index method instead of my other method. Do I have to create a complete new view for the other method for this to work individually?

example:

in my controller I have:

```
 def index

  @search = Post.search do #Post.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20 
  order_by(:updated_at, :desc)
   end
   @posts = @search.results 
 end



 def local

  @search = Post.search do #Post.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  with(:school, current_user.school)
  facet(:school)
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20 
  order_by(:updated_at, :desc)
  end
   @posts = @search.results

   render :index  
end
```

if I flip the methods and make index the local and vice versa, then when I search, the search filters results based on :school, but the way the code is, I have a link to the local action and everything is filtered but when I search, I get results no matter the school field

There's gotta be a better solution than to have to copy my index.html.erb and change it to local.html.erb

Thanks!

Comment: ok, I think I can have an if statement in the view and pass different params, so I can rename the params search to local search in local method

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

Ok so I renamed my local method's param to local search like below:

```
def local

  @search = Post.search do #Post.search do
  fulltext params[:localsearch]                   #changed from 'search' to localsearch'
  with(:school, current_user.school)
  facet(:school)
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20 
  order_by(:updated_at, :desc)
 end
 @posts = @search.results

 render :index  
end
```

then in the view application.html.erb I added if statements like so:

```
    <% if current_page?(posts_path) %>
      <div class="pull-left" style="display: inline-block;"> <div role="search">      
      <%= form_tag posts_path, :method => :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: 'search' , autofocus: false ,:placeholder => "search",:class =>'fruute-input', :size => 30 %>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="mybutton" >
          <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg" style = "color: white;"></i>                     
        </button>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
        
     <% if current_page?(index_path) %>
      <div class="pull-left" style="display: inline-block;"> <div role="search">      
      <%= form_tag index_path, :method => :get do %>
        #in this next line I pass :localsearch to local method;
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:localsearch], id: 'search' , autofocus: false ,:placeholder => "search",:class =>'fruute-input', :size => 30 %>  
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="mybutton" >
          <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg" style = "color: white;"></i>                     
        </button>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

For those in the future that want this to work with sunspot:

in the model:

```
  validates :price, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
  searchable do
    text :title
    text :author 
    text :course
    text :school
    text :email
    text :description
    text :price
    integer :id
    time :updated_at


string :school #notice, facet fields must be string, just add the field from above and diplicate it as string if text
```

end

**BAM!**